# How to render specific template if two app have same template name?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I render a specific template in Django? I have created three apps for my project. Each app contains a templates folder. The project structure is as follows:

```
├───Project
├───app1
│   ├───templates
├───app2
│   ├───templates
├───app3
│   ├───templates
```

In my app2 and app3, I have templates with the same name. I want to render the template from app3 but the template is rendering from app2. I am using the following code.

In app3.views.py

```
return render(request, "template_name.html")
```

By using the above code, the template gets rendered from app2. I want template should be rendered from app3.

Comment: All template configuration is in Settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-OPTIONS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recommendation is to use a folder structure like app1/templates/app1/ in order to avoid such kind of collisions. Same for static files.

See also [docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03) and search for "template namespacing"